# get_children() not working properly – Only on one post?

Tags: images, get-posts, children, get-children

Client wants to show how many images await the reader in a post. I say: easy peazy. Now I realize: I lied.

The system only uses galleries, even for single pictures.

```
$images = get_children(array(
    "post_parent" => $post->ID, // $post->ID gives the right ID.
    "post_status" => "any",
    "post_type" => "attachment",
    "post_mime_type" => "image"
));

count($images); // only post with id 12 shows correctly 14 entries
```

In one post (ID 12, an eaaarly test entry) `$images` is filled with the correct amount of entries. In every other post I tested `$images` is wrongfully empty.

I even copied the exact same text (from the "Text"-Tab of TinyMCE, not "Visual") to post with ID 298. Still empty `$images`. Same custom fields. Both have a thumbnail (even if I delete it, no change) – Same taxonomy-settings..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`get_children`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/) function retrieves posts (an upoaded image is also a post) that are dependent on the post with a certain ID. An image becomes a child of a post when it is uploaded while editing that post. It does not become a child of a post when it is reused.

So if you are writing post A and upload image B, B will become a child of A. If you then write post C and include image B in a gallery, B will not become a child of C. If you use `get_children` on C, you will find nothing.

What you are looking for is [`get_post_galleries`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_galleries/).

Comment: Okay, that clarifies it. Thank you. I'm curious: Can you provide an example where this behavior is benefitial? And why the hell is such an important concept nowhere to be found in the Wordpress Docs? Back2Topic: just to make sure we're on the same page: You suggest to `get_post_galleries($post->ID, false)` data and manually go through each index and add the IDs string to a `$toCount` var, to then explode and count it? And: How can I add single images without galleries to the count, if I some day decide to support them?

Comment: If you want to be really sure you get all the images, you would have to make a filter for `the_content` and count all occurences of `<img`.

Comment: So the only way, you say, is going through the contents rendered html .. Not so cool when I want the option to ignore duplicates. Wow. Wouldn't have thought counting a posts number of images is so exotic, that Wordpress doesn't have a native solution for it.. Is there a less performance demanding way then Regex to count `<img`s?

Comment: I can't get it done... `get_the_content()` doesn't render the shortcodes, so there are no `<img `s to count, and `the_content()` immediately prints the output ...

Comment: You can use `get_the_content` and apply `do_shortcode` to the result to get the html with shortcodes expanded.

Comment: And two answer your previous comment: since you can type anything you like in the content field, WP would have no other option but to apply regex to the content in order to find img-tags. Actually, that is what it does to find shortcode-tags.